# How to pass parameters to module constructor when calling a HMVC module in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I just want to know on how to pass parameters in module 
constructor?

Here is the code that is wrote but its not functioning well.

//Here is the main controller

class Main extends MX_Controller
{
            public function _*construct()
         {

                  parent::*_construct();
         }

```
 public function index()
 {

  // sample parameter
    $aparam = array(
      'param1' => 'param value1',
      'param2' => 'param value2'
    );

      $this->load->module('dashboard',$aparam);
  }
```

}

// Here is "dashboard" module controller

class Dashboard extends MX_Controller
  {

public function __construct($aparam)
        {
                     //output param value
                     // want to get this value
                     echo $aparam['param1'];
                     echo $aparam['param2'];
       }
}

Please help. thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so just to clarify, I don't know what "HMVC" stands for but I did notice that if you are trying to use the codeigniter framework then when you create a controller class you must extend the "CI_Controller" class not the "MX_Controller".

Here is a reference page in the codeigniter manual:
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html

If you are trying to create a stand alone class that interacts with your code somehow, Codeigniter allows for this via "libraries". A library is just a class.

Here is the reference page in the codeigniter manual:
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Comment: HMVC is Hierarchical Model View Controller.
You can developed in ci by using module HMVC has its own controller,view and model.